# opengl - camera cannot see object when glOrtho is used

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinate-transformation, orthographic

I'm new to *OpenGL* and I'm trying to understand how the projection matrix works in it.

To create a simple case, I define a triangle in the world space and its coordinates are:

> (0,1,0), (1,0,0), (-1,0,0)

I set the modelview matrix and projection matrix as below:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(
    0, 0, 2,
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -0.1, -2.0); // does not work
// glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 0.1, 2.0); // works
```

From my understanding, `gluLookAt()` is used to set the viewing matrix. Since `OpenGL` does not have a concept of "camera", and thus it transforms the entire world to reach the effect of a camera. In the above code, I assume the "camera" is at (0,0,2), looking at (0,0,0). So *OpenGL* internally moves the triangle backwards along `z` axis to `z=-2`.

To define a view frustum, `glOrtho()` get 6 parameters. To make the triangle visible in the frustum, I set the `near` and `far` value to `-0.1` and `-2.0` respectively and this should indicate that the frustum include `[-0.1, -2.0]` on `z` axis.

---

I searched for similar questions and found out someone states that the last two parameters of `glOrtho()` is in fact `-near` and `-far`. But if this is correct, the following code should work(**but it doesn't**):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(
    0, 0, -2, // changed 2 to -2, thus the triangle should be transformed to z=2?
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -0.1, -2.0); // -near=-0.1, -far=-2.0, thus the frustum should include [0.1, 2.0], thus include the triangle
```

**If I'm correct, the triangle should be drawn on the screen, so there must be something wrong with my code. Can anyone help?**

Comment: As Rabbid76 mentions the fixed function pipeline is deprecated. Suggested you learn the modern one. Good lessons here: http://learnopengl.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note, that the fixed function pipeline matrix stack and drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since more than 10 years.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

If you use a view matrix like this:

```
gluLookAt(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Then the values for the near and the far plane have to be positive when you set up the the projection matrix,

```
glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 0.1, 2.0);
```

because, `gluLookAt` transforms the vertices to view space (in view space the z axis points out of the viewport), but the projection matrix inverts the z-axis.

But be careful, since the triangle is at `z=0`

```
(0,1,0), (1,0,0), (-1,0,0)
```

and the distance from the camera to the triangle is 2, because  of the view matrix, the triangle is placed exactly on the far plane (which is 2.0 too). I recommend to increase the distance to the far plane from 2.0 to (e.g.) 3.0:

```
glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 0.1, 3.0);
```

---

If you change the view matrix,

```
gluLookAt(0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

then still the (view space) z-axis points out of the viewport, but you look at the "back" side of the triangle. The triangle is still in the center of the view (0, 0, 0), but the camera position has changed. The triangle is still in front of the camera.

If you would do

```
gluLookAt(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0);
```

then you would look away from the triangle. You would have to project the backside of the view to the viewport to "see" the triangle (`glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -0.1, -3.0);`).

---

Further note, that [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) multiplies the current matrix  by the orthographic projection matrix. This means you should set the identity matrix, before you use `glOrtho`, as you do it with the model view matrix:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 0.1, 2.0);
```

---

**Explanation**

The projection, view and model matrix interact together to present the objects (meshes) of a scene on the viewport.
The model matrix defines the position orientation and scale of a single object (mesh) in the worldspace of the scene.
The view matrix defines the position and viewing direction of the observer (viewer) within the scene.
The projection matrix defines the area (volume) with respect to the observer (viewer) projected onto the viewport.

At orthographic projection, this area (volume) is defined by 6 distances (left, right, bottom, top, near and far) to the viewer's position.

**View matrix**

The view coordinates system describes the direction and position from which the scene is looked at. The view matrix transforms from the wolrd space to the view (eye) space.

If the coordiante system of the view space is a [Right-handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) system, then the X-axis points to the left, the Y-axis up and the Z-axis out of the view (Note in a right hand system the Z-Axis is the cross product of the X-Axis and the Y-Axis).

[image]

**Projection matrix**

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of the view on a scene, to 2D points on the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates. The NDC are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1).
 Every geometry which is out of the clippspace is clipped.

At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the view space are linearly mapped to clip space coordinates and the clip space coordinates are equal to the normalized device coordinates, because the `w` component is 1 (for a cartesian input coordinate).
The values for left, right, bottom, top, near and far define a box. All the geometry which is inside the volume of the box is "visible" on the viewport.

[image]

The Orthographic Projection Matrix looks like this:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far 

2/(r-l)         0               0               0
0               2/(t-b)         0               0
0               0               -2/(f-n)        0
-(r+l)/(r-l)    -(t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    1
```

The z-axis is inverted by the projection matrix.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. So the `near` and `far` parameters of `glOrtho()` is actually defining the near/far clipping distances from the eye and their signs mean whether the viewing volume (I suppose this is the same as the frustum?) is in front of /behind the eye, instead of actual coordinates in the space?

Comment: Also I'm still a little confused about what you mean by "the z-axis is inverted by the projection matrix". I mean, the projection matrix defines a frustum and maps the 3D frustum to a 2D plane (clip space?). And the z-axis is inverted when coordinates are transformed from that 2D plane to the NDC space. I suppose this is because NDC uses left-handed coordinate system. So, I think the "inversion" does not influence the `view->clip` process and the signs of the `near`/`far` param is not related with this inversion of z-axis. (I'm just so confused of whether should I use positive/negative value.)

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Use a view matrix and positive values for the near and far plane. The part `-2/(f-n)` invertes the z-coordiante when a vertex is transformed by the projection matrix.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y At orthographic projection there is no "frustum", because a frustum is a truncated pyramid. The view volume at orthographic projection is a box. At perspective projection it would be a frustum.